# Find who made changes to FB app settings (FB login redirect URLs list)

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-settings

Good day!

On one of our apps list of URLs allowed as redirects from FB login has mysteriously changed. I don't believe in wonders so probably someone has changed them. This change has caused several damages and currently we are discussing blame and damage cover as well as prevention of future incidents with our customer.

Question: can I see somehow who and when changed FB app settings or ask someone in FB support about that? There are many people having admin access to app and without tracking their actions undesired changes will happen again sooner or later.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retroactively, you probably can't.

But you can set your app up to send a notification about any changes that occur, and by whom their are made.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security#app-settings-security

> **Update Notification**
>
> In the event that such a takeover does take place, we have built a notification system to expedite discovery and recovery from such takeovers. This notifies relevant individuals when any app settings are changed using the App Dashboard. The notification contains information about what change was made and by whom.
>
> An app can register an email address to which these notifications should be sent in the Advanced tab of app settings.